# Mysql fetch_array_assoc not getting first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM textos");

         $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<b>ID:</b> ".$row['id'].", <b>Titulo:</b>".$row['titulo'].", <b>Texto:</b>".$row['texto'].", <b>Presentes:</b>".$row['presentes']."<br/>";
         }
```

But when I run it, only from the second id on that are echoed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetches the first row:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Starts fetching from the second row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Get rid of the first call to `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 3):

You have duplicated `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`. Only the while(...) should contain it.